# How to disable the use of certain words in categories

Tags: taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I would like to "censor" the creation of some categories, meaning, I don't want that some terms/words could be used when creating categories.

Can anyone help?

Thank you all.

Comment: Would it be an alternative to manipulate them automatically if special strings are used, or would only be restrict to publish help you?

Comment: If special defined strings (like for example in an array) were used would do!